# What does the -W parameter of tar actually do?

Tags: backup, tar

I am using `tar` to pack up some data. Before I move it to an archive, I want to check the integrity of the tarball. According to the man page, the parameter `-W` does a verification:

> -W, --verify
> Verify the archive after writing it.

I tested this and it seems to do something:

```
$ tar cvWf tartest.tar tartest/
tartest/
tartest/dir1/
tartest/dir1/bar
tartest/dir2/
tartest/dir2/foobar
Verify tartest/
Verify tartest/dir1/
Verify tartest/dir1/bar
Verify tartest/dir2/
Verify tartest/dir2/foobar
```

But what exactly does `tar` verify here? The presence of the files? File size? MD5 sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some digging to figure out. In the file [`src/compare.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/compare.c) in the [Git repo for tar](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=tar), we find a function named [`verify_volume`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/compare.c#n527) (on line 527 at the time of writing), which contains the following comment

> Verifying an archive is meant to check if the physical media got it correctly, so try to defeat clever in-memory buffering pertaining to this particular media.  On Linux, for example, the floppy drive would not even be accessed for the whole verification.

That explains what it tries to do, but as to *how* it does it, we need to look at the code for the function. It starts off by comparing the headers to make sure they match, and if they do, it runs the function [`diff_archive`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/compare.c#n461) (line 461 at the time of writing), which goes item by item inside the archive, and when it encounters a file*, it will run the function [`diff_file`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/compare.c#n187) (line 187). It starts by checking a few easy things, such as file type and size (and others). If all of those are correct, it (for a normal file) goes and verifies each block of the file (in the [`read_and_process`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/compare.c#n120) function, line 120). For [sparse files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126760/what-is-a-sparse-file-and-why-do-we-need-it), it calls the [`sparse_diff_file`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/sparse.c#n698) (line 698) in [`src/sparse.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/sparse.c), which checks each region of the file** using the [`check_sparse_region`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/sparse.c#n607) function (line 607), also in [`src/sparse.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/sparse.c).

*It does other things for other types of archived data, such as directories

**It checks each region in a similar way that it checks an entire normal (non-sparse) file

Comment: Oh wow, so it does way more, than I was expecting - great! Thanks a lot!